# How can I de-duplicate repeated characters in a Java string?

Tags: java, string

Does there exist a method in Java which lets you transform a string like `how________are_______you` to `how_are_you`, i.e. just keep one `_` when it is duplicated.

Comment: yes, you can use regex replacement to do that, `String.replaceAll()`.

Answer (score 11):

Use regexp replacer:

```
string.replaceAll("_+", "_")
```

Comment: Well, this regex is obviously better !

Answer (score 0):

you could solve it with a regular expression! match duplicate occurrences of `_` and replace it with a single `_`. i don't think there is a predefined method.

Answer (score 0):

use [**String#replaceAll(regex, str)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
    String s="how__are__you";
    System.out.print(s.replaceAll("_+", "_"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java's ReplaceAll() function. Java has one of the best online documentations of any language I suggest that you go and try them out.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

Simple method

```
 str = str.replaceAll("_+", "_");
```

Much efficient method

```
str = str.replaceAll("_{2,}", "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

without regex you could use a little creepy, selfwritten method like this

```
private static String replaceLetters(String text, char rchar) {
     String newtext;
     for(int i=0;i<text.length;i++) {
       if(text.charAt(i)!=rchar) {
         newtext = newtext + text.charAt(i);
        }
       else {
        newtext = newtext + newtext.charAt(i);
        for(int j=i+1;j<text.length;j++) {
          if(text.charAt(j)!=rchar) {
            i = j;
            break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return newtext;
}
```

sorry a bit oldschool ;)