# Java: how to replace multiple carriage return by only one?

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to clean the user comment:

- remove all duplicated carriage return
- remove all carriage return at the end

Example:

```
"Hello guys,
it's my example,



to try to clean


my comment
"
```

And I would like:

```
"Hello guys,
it's my example,

to try to clean

my comment"
```

I tried with `s.replaceAll("(?:\\n|\\r)", "");` but it doesn't work for my first case.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Try `s = s.replaceAll("(\\R){2,}|\r+$", "$1");` (replace `\r` with `\\R` if you mean line breaks at the end, not CR, carriage returns).

Comment: Your example is not consistent with your description of what you want.  You seem to be changing sequences of three or more line terminators to two, which is not well described by "remove all duplicated carriage return".

Comment: From my opinion SO's example is quite good and understandable.

Comment: I'm also uncertain whether you are using "carriage return" in the specific sense of  Unicode character U+000D, or whether you are using it as a generic synonym for "line terminator".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think it is clear what does he mean: `\n` and `\r`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I de-duplicate repeated characters in a Java string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878214/how-can-i-de-duplicate-repeated-characters-in-a-java-string)

Comment: @Andremoniy, yes, I see that you are confident enough in your interpretation of the question to write an answer based on it.  Myself, I am without confidence that even the OP himself knows precisely what he wants, so I will reserve judgement until he clarifies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be quite easy:

```
s.replaceAll("[\n\r]{2,}","\n\n")
```

it  replaces all sequential carriage returns (equal or greater than 2) into two carriage returns.

**UPDATE**: @John Bollinger has pointed on very good thing: *"...this approach will convert single Windows-style line terminators to double Unix-style line terminators..."*

So probably more better and more general approach will be:

```
s.replaceAll("(\n{2,})|(\r{2,})|((\r\n){2,})","\n\n")
```

**UPDATE-2**: To remove leading carriage returns also perform: `.replaceAll("[\n\r]+$","")`

Comment: `[\n|\r]` does not do what you think it does, because it matches the `|` character too.

Comment: @Andreas you are absolutely right, I was too hurrying :) Thank you for pointing this

Comment: Thank you very much Andre! Other question: how can I remove all spaces before a carriage return?

Comment: @anthony I'm not sure that I correctly understand what do you mean

Comment: @Andremoniy in this example 'Hello it's my test       \r', I want to remove all spaces between "test" word and the carriage return.

Comment: `replaceAll("\s+\n","\n")`?

Comment: Among its effects, this approach will convert single Windows-style line terminators to double Unix-style line terminators.  I remain uncertain what the OP actually wants, but that particular conversion seems questionable.

Comment: Upon closer examination I will agree with you

Comment: Yes, I see it.  Unfortunately, the suggested revision is altogether ineffective on (multiple) Windows-style line terminators, which of course are two-character sequences representable in Java as `"\r\n"`.  Your new regex won't match `"\r\n\r\n" at all.

Comment: Yep, after writing my commentary I've also noticed that, now updated

Comment: Ok, the current version looks better to me.  It does not accommodate mixed line termination, which does sometimes occur in the wild, but I doubt the OP has contemplated that or is looking for a solution that handles it.

Comment: This answer only covers half the question, i.e, it doesn't *"remove all carriage return at the end"*. It also doesn't cover the extra *"remove all spaces before a carriage return"* [asked for in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785756/java-how-to-replace-multiple-carriage-return-by-only-one/43786880#comment74612772_43785874).

Comment: @Andreas that's true. I would be happy delete this answer, but I can't

Comment: @Andreas Since your answer is much better than mine and I vote to accept it instead of mine, I've updated my as well to cover missed OP's requirement

Answer (score 1):

Including the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785756/java-how-to-replace-multiple-carriage-return-by-only-one#comment74612772_43785874) you left for another answer, you want 3 things to happen:

- 3 or more linebreaks should be reduced to 2, leaving at most one blank line.
- All linebreaks at the end of text should be removed.
- Spaces at the end of lines should be removed.

If you want all of that in a single regex, here it is:

```
replaceAll("(?:\\R|\\s)+$|[ \t]*(\\R)[ \t]*(\\R)(?:[ \t]*\\R)+", "$1$2")
```

The question uses the phrase "carriage return", which in Java is the `\r` character, but the sample code indicates that it actually means "line separator", or "linebreak" as it's called in the regex documentation, which is the [`\R` regex pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending):

> Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to
>      `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`

First part of the regex above (`(?:\\R|\\s)+$`) is for eliminating all (`+`) linebreaks (`\R`) and/or whitespace characters (`\s`) at the end of input (`$`).

The second part uses the subpattern `[ \t]*\\R` 3 times. The subpattern matches a linebreak and all immediately preceding spaces.

To match a subpattern 3 or more times, you would normally use `X{3,}`, but we want to captur the first two linebreaks, so we can retain them, without knowing what kind of linebreak they are (e.g. Windows vs Linux), we we instead write the subpattern twice, with capture, then match 1 or more after that.

Finally we replace that with the two captured linebreaks. If the first part of the pattern matches, then it's replace with nothing, i.e. it's removed. If the second part matches, it's replaced with the first two matched linebreak, i.e. those linebreasks are retained.

Comment: @anthony, it would be better if you will accept this answer as more full and correct

Answer (score -2):

Yet another solution which fulfills your requirements:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str =
            "\"Hello guys,\n" +
            "it's my example,\n" +
            "\n\r" +
            "\n" +
            "\n\r" +
            "to try to clean\n" +
            "\n\r" +
            "\n" +
            "my comment\n" +
            "\"";
    System.out.println("Before\n\n" + str);
    System.out.println("\n\nAfter:\n\n" + str
            .replaceAll("(\n|\n\r){3,}", "\n\n")
            .replaceAll("(\n|\n\r)+\"$", "\""));
}
```

**Output**

```
Before

"Hello guys,
it's my example,



to try to clean


my comment
"


After:

"Hello guys,
it's my example,

to try to clean

my comment"
```

Comment: Doesn't work if linebreaks are Windows style `\r\n` pairs.

Comment: @Andreas: I have not read about `\n\ŗ` as a requirement but here you go. It was just a tiny tweak.

Comment: If you look at the sample code in the question, it has `(?:\\n|\\r)`. If you just read the question text *literally*, it says "carriage return", i.e. `\r`, not `\n`. So a strict read means `\r` only, and a loose read means either Window or Linus line-separators. If on Windows, you'd obviously want to retain Window style line-separators. Similarly, if on Linux, you'd obviously want to retain Window style line-separators. You code doesn't do that.